# how to send notification on chrome?

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, flutter-web

I am developing an app where I get notifications at certain situations,
and I wanted to make it as a webapp so I don't have to make a developer account on Android/iOS.
But I haven't found any method to send notification on web browser environment, what I found only supports Android/iOS.
Is there any way to do it in web browser environment?

Comment: Want to send a push notification from a server to Flutter application running on Chrome?

Comment: yes, a push notification to a flutter app on Chrome